# Class 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I am getting the below error when I try to load any page on my site.

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError Class
>   'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' not found
>
> in ProviderRepository.php (line 208)

I have been following a tutorial as well as referring to the Laravel documentation.

I have seen other questions posed on here and attempted to fix by following suggestions on those questions. Things I have done include:

- Change to socialite 2.0
- composer update
- composer dump-autoload -o
- artisan config:cache
- php artisan config:clear

I have laravel v5.6.18.

I can see socialite referenced in all the files which have been discussed on other posts, and I have included what I have below:

LoginController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
```

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "laravel/socialite": "~2.0.0",
```

autoload_psr4.php

```
'Laravel\\Socialite\\' => array($vendorDir . '/laravel/socialite/src'),
```

app.php

```
Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,

'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do `composer require laravel/socialite` on the server. I have a local copy of the laravel project and I am hosting it (not localhost). I pulled the latest version of the project but I needed to install socialite on the server as well.

I realised this was the case when I went into the autoload_psr4.php file on the server and the return array did not include a lot of what I could see locally.

Comment: first of all, did you commit the `vendor` directory? if yes, perhaps you dont need to `composer require` again. not to mention if `laravel/socialite` already stated in `composer.json` you will only need to fire `composer install` i believe. also, its a habit to fire `composer dump-autoload` first to ensure all modules are actually listed in auto load files.

Comment: No I did not commit the vendor directory. Insert facepalm here.

Comment: thats ok, on most convention we dont commit `vendor` directory. but we do commit `composer.json` and `composer.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i forget to clear the config cache. Try to clear it

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: This is not a clear answer, please add more details to the OP's question for others' later reference. Thank you :+

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by going to the `bootstrap/cache/config.php` then removed `'Laravel\\Socialite\\SocialiteServiceProvider',` under `array` and also removed `'Laravel\\Socialite\\Facades\\Socialite',`  under `aliases` and then run `composer dump-autoload` and `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you removed Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider package from your Laravel project. (Solution: Step 1)
Or in case you don't install even though already pre-build script needs that package installation. (Solution : Step 2)

1. Remove the package clearly.

> Remove bootstrap/cache/config.php and packages.php files. Remove the package lines from config/app.php providers and aliases array. `php artisan config:clear` or `php artisan optimize:clear`

2. Install Socialite package

> `composer require laravel/socialite` follow this guide https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/socialite

Answer (score -2):

install the package using following code

```
composer require socialiteproviders/facebook
```